# How does negating an existential quantifier work?

Tags: logic

I'm revising counterexamples for my logic exam next term, and one of them has me absolutely stumped. I have to provide a counterexample to refute the following claim:

```
∀x∃yPxyy v ∃x¬∃y∃zPxyz is logically true
```

The solutions say that the answer is:

```
Domain of discourse: {0, 1}
|P| in the L2-structure: {<0, 0, 1>, <1, 0, 1>}
```

Now, I can see that to refute the claim you have to show that there is a structure where both sides of the disjunction are false, and I can see how the first half of it is made false, but the negation of the existential in the second half is confusing me a lot - I can't wrap my head around the concept of it. Why is <1, 0, 1> impossible for the second half to yield in this domain of discourse?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider **Px01**; it is clearly *true* for both cases : **x=0** and **x=1**, i.e. for *all* elements of the *domain*.

Thus, **∀x∃y∃zPxyz** is *true*. But this is equivalent to : **¬∃x¬∃y∃zPxyz** which is the *negation* of the right disjunct.

Comment: Why are the two equivalent?

Comment: @user18883 because : "all crows are black" means "does not exist a crow that is not black".

Comment: Ahhh yes I see. So how would I deduce from just the original question that  it was <1, 0, 1> specifically that would disprove the right disjunct?

Comment: Ah, no, don't worry, I get it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The second half is saying that for some object x, the relation P is never instantiated with x as the first term (there are no y and z such that Pxyz). To refute the claim just make sure that P applies to all possible objects as first terms. Here P is instantiated for both 0 and 1 as first terms so the model indeed refutes the claim.

You can view the negation as applying to both existentials combined (it's not true that there exists a y and a z such that...).